# How to calculate area of triangle having its points 2D coordinates?

Tags: geometry, linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

We have points A, B & C in 2D plane. How having point coordinates $(x, y)$ to calculate area of triangle formed by them?

Comment: English, please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make Rahul's comment more explicit, the determinant formula

$$\frac12 \begin{vmatrix}x_1&y_1&1\\x_2&y_2&1\\x_3&y_3&1\end{vmatrix}$$

where the $(x_i,y_i)$ are the coordinates of the corners, gives the (signed) area of the triangle. For a guaranteed positive result, the points are to be taken anticlockwise.

Comment: Straying slightly off-topic, I never noticed before I saw your answer that the obvious way to write the absolute value of a determinant is pretty ugly: $\big\lvert\lvert A\rvert\big\rvert$... (Of course one may write $\lvert\det A\rvert$, but one needs foresight for that!)

Comment: @Rahul: Yeah, the couple of times I had to use both determinants and norms, I always used $|\det\mathbf{A}|$.

Answer (score 0):

If by square you mean the area, [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) is your friend.  Just calculate the side lengths and the semiperimeter.

Comment: If the coordinates of the points are known, Heron's formula is overkill. The area is just half the cross product of two edges.

Comment: @Rahul: Right you are.